# In Vuetify breakpoints, is 960px considered 'sm' or 'md'

Tags: vuetify.js

Referencing this page:  https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/

I can't tell if 960px is sm or md.
"sm" is considered to be `600px > < 960px` and
"md" is considered to be `960px > < 1264px`

Since there is no "less than or equal to" being used, I'm not sure how to read that.

Am I supposed to read `> <` as left-side inclusive, right-side exclusive?  Is that spelled out anywhere?

I feel like an idiot for having to ask, but seems like it'd be simple to use <= or >= but they chose not to use that widely accepted syntax.  Is there a reason?  Is that `> <` used elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a short answer: **960px is md**.

Some investigations: according to [vuetify sources](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss):

```js
$grid-breakpoints: map-deep-merge(
  (
    'xs': 0,
    'sm': 600px,
    'md': 960px,
    'lg': 1280px - 16px,
    'xl': 1920px - 16px
  ),
  $grid-breakpoints
);
```

can be interpreted as:

- xs: 0 ... 599px
- sm: 600 ... 959px
- md: 960 ... 1263px
- lg: 1264 ... 1903px
- xl: 1904px ... +∞

You can also check these breakpoints in dynamic by resizing [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/NWMyEve)

Comment: Awesome, thx.  Using `v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp"` on my component also confirmed that 960px is md.  I'm just confused why they would use a vague way to explain the values.  You'd think it should be black and white in the doc.  Thx for helping me clarify.